# How to even speach loudness?

Tags: amplifier, loudness

I am working with a recording (some speach) where it has parts with different loudness (amplitude) so I would like to make all those parts evenly loud. Actualy, I would like to make every word spoken even. Is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a compressor for this kind of processing.
Settings should be as follow.

- Low Treshold
- High Ratio
- Short attack
- Short release

The previous settings are just mentioned as an example.
You 'll need of course to adapt them to your input source.

Loudness is a bit like everything, a matter of context. In order to increase the loudness feeling put a gater before the compressor as a referral for the auditor. If you don't do that the listener will get exhausted quickly and probably won't be as concentrated on the speech as he was at the beginning.

For more accuracy you can also use a multi-band compressor.
Same process but on certain frequency domains

Hope this helped, Cheers,